# Mysql Database Attacks other than Sql Injection

Tags: mysql, database, security, sql-injection, database-security

I am using mysqli prepared statements and bound variables.

1. Then to prevent sql injection, am I need to do anything else(eg: data type validation, filtering, sanitize, string escape etc ) with user input ?
2. Is there any other way of attacking MySql database other than Sql Injection ?

Comment: Sure - stealing a badly done password and just busting in to steal data.

Comment: Yes, there are. Have a look at the history of [publicly known vulnerabilities in MySQL](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-185/Mysql.html).

Comment: You can't attack what you can't access, so your MySQL server should be firewalled off from being accessible from the Internet, and, ideally, should not be accessible from any machine in your network that does not require access, so that those machines, if compromised, don't provide an intermediate path to access it.  Your application should be using a mysql account with only the privileges that it requires, and not more.

Comment: I means the attack through my web application only, and not in other ways. Also I am using shared hosting from Godaddy. I can't set privileges to the mysql user

Answer (score 2):

To prevent SQL injection you have to **format your query properly**.
Every literal that have to be added to the query *dynamically*, have to be properly formatted.
Not only data literals like strings and numbers but all of them, including operators and identifiers. 
The only proper way to make values formatted is prepared statements.

For the identifiers and operators you will need also filtering, to let only allowed ones into query.

Whatever *user input* should not be involved at all. It's destination, not source that matters.

> Is there any other way of attacking MySql database other than Sql Injection ?

sure thing. But the topic is too broad to make you secured by means of a forum post. Better hire a DBA.

Comment: @Your Common Sense          "Whatever user input should not be involved at all. It's destination, not source that matters." - I can't understand

Comment: You should format properly **everything** that goes into query, not just a certain subset of data, no matter how you call it.